# Conditional recoding gives no error, but no changes either

Tags: r, conditional-statements, recode

I am trying to recode some variables in an experiment with two lists (`"list1"` and `"list2"`).

The `id` was supposed to match between each experimental condition, but unfortunately they don't. The only solution I have found to fix this was with the `recode_if()` function:

```r
olives <- olives %>%
    mutate(id = recode_if(id, id == 1 & list == "list1", "1" = "9"))

olives
```

Although R gives me no error message, I am not seeing any changes.

My intention with this is something like the following:

- If item is in list1 and `id` is 1, change `id = 1` to `id = 9`
- If item is in list1 and `id` is 2, change `id = 2` to `id = 10`

*etc.*

Where could be the error?

```
 dput(head(olives))

structure(list(subject = c(NA, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128), X2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), birth_year = c(NA, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
1997), X4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), birth_month = c(NA, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), native_language = c(NA, 
"Greek", "Greek", "Greek", "Greek", "Greek"), X8 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Multilingual = c(NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes"), X10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Dyslexic = c(NA, "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No"), X12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sex = c(NA, 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), X14 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), HandPreference = c(NA, "Right", "Right", 
"Right", "Right", "Right"), X16 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    rt = c(NA, NA, NA, 5602, NA, NA), stimulus = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    "Η μεταφορική εταιρία είναι στη Λάρισα", 
    NA, NA), trial_index = c(NA, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22), time_elapsed = c(NA, 
    139855, 146511, 152621, 159248, 167898), list = c(NA, "list1", 
    "list1", "list1", "list1", "list1"), button_pressed = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), rt1 = c(NA, 313, 216, NA, 246, 191), 
    rt2 = c(NA, 545, 139, NA, 196, 327), rt3 = c(NA, 337, 416, 
    NA, 212, 320), rt4 = c(NA, 139, 373, NA, 314, 426), rt5 = c(NA, 
    396, 326, NA, 345, 427), rt6 = c(NA, 333, 631, NA, 540, 481
    ), id = c(NA, 14, 1, 1, 7, 11), item_type = c(NA, "ZZM", 
    "ZYM", "QZYM", "ZYM", "ZZMM"), expected_answer = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, "Λάθος", NA, NA), answer = c(NA, NA, NA, "Λάθος", 
    NA, NA), correct = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA), integer_correct = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `%in%`: The issue might be exact match with `==`.

```
library(dplyr)

olives %>% 
  mutate(id = case_when(item %in% list1 & id == 1 ~9, 
                        item %in% list2 & id == 2 ~10,
                        TRUE ~ id))
```

Comment: It is saying the object "item" could not be found. 

To make it clear, "list1" and "list2" are variables in a column called "list". I tried substituting "item" for that, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Best would be to provide some data: eg. `dput(head(olives))`!

Comment: Sorry, could be more specific on how the code would look like? I have almost zero experience with R

Comment: Write in your console `dput(head(olives))` then copy the output from your console and paste it to your question via `edit` at the bottom of your question!

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for continuing to help! I have added the output in my question

Comment: After all, I came up with a different solution. I created two new columns for each list and matched the id numbers using this pattern:

attach(olives)
olives$list2[id == 1 & list == "list2"] <- "9"
detach(olives)